# what must i prepare to have a layover in doha for 10 hours for indonesian passport?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, turkey, qatar, indonesian-citizens

I am an Indonesian citizen fully vaccinated with the sinovac (coronavac) vaccine.

I am planning to visit turkey for a 10-day trip.

what must i prepare to have a layover in Doha for 10 hours?

Comment: For completeness, where are you travelling *from*? Will the flight be a single booking (one PNR) or two separate tickets?

Comment: from indonesia, one PNR (single booking).